# Patch Qmake to use specifics ( and relative) paths

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I want to distribute a SDK I made using Qt.
For this, I have made a script to generate a tarball containing my libs (libmysdk.so, etc.) and also an embedded headless "minimal Qt" (-no-gui, -no-widgets, etc.) with a qmake binary.

The goal here is to allow the user to developp an application using my Sdk, filling the .pro with whatever he wants, and make him call qmake to generate the appropriate Makefile.

My problem here is that the generated Makefile contains absolutes and relative paths to the place I compiled my qmake locally (/home/john/mystuff/myproject etc.) making it not portable at all.

In the Makefile:

```
CC            = /opt/arm-2015.02-ct-ng/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc
[...]
INCPATH       = -I. -Iinclude -I../../home/john/mystuff/myproject/builddir
```

I'm looking for a way to force qmake to use the "embedded Qt installation" I provide in the tarball.

I tried 2 things:

```
./qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_HEADERS"
```

will print the (wrong) absolute path. But

```
./qmake -set "QT_INSTALL_HEADERS" "foo/bar/something"
```

Will not update the QT_INSTALL_HEADERS value. My guess is that builtins values cannot be changed in the qmake binary, am I right ?

My second try was made using this https://github.com/qtproject/qtsdk
and more specifically the patch_qmake_qt_key.py whose goal is apparently to update some keys (builtins or not) in the binary.
But I tried several "keys" name, with always the same error:

```
Could not find given key: QT_INSTALL_HEADERS

Could not find given key: INSTALL_HEADERS

Could not find given key: PLEASE_WORKS
etc.
```

(Is there a place/documentation where I can find those 'keys names' ?)

Is there a way after qmake compilation (or maybe before) to set the paths, ideally relative to the tarball root, or if not possible, a way to set the path absolute (maybe by calling a ./install.sh which update the qmake binary with some combination of pwd and stuff.

Many thanks !

Comment: I don’t understand the problem and what you want to achieve. One is not meant to share the generated Makefile, but to run qmake locally to generate a new one out of the shared .pro file. QMake will also use the Qt it’s part of.

Comment: I don't want to share the makefile, I want to share the .pro (the user will edit it to add his own files) and the qmake binary. But I want to generate the qmake binary with my local Qt installation and then "patch" it to use an embeded Qt I provide in the tarball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in suspecting that it is all about key names, because they differ between external and internal representations: in particular, what is visible outside as `QT_INSTALL_HEADERS`, is actually `qt_hdrspath` inside `qmake` executable file.

Even more so, the above only applies to QMake from Qt 3.x and 4.x. Since Qt 5.x, QMake defines only a narrow set of base paths, — practically, `qt_prfxpath` (plus `qt_epfxpath`) and `qt_hpfxpath`, — that correspond to `QT_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `QT_HOST_PREFIX`, respectively. All other locations are computed on top of these prefixes, with hard-coded subpaths which cannot be changed so easily as base variables, — at least not automatically, because they can only be found by looking for their exact value, and because there is little to none extra room reserved for their value. For example, `QT_INSTALL_HEADERS` is computed as `QT_INSTALL_PREFIX` + `"/include/qt5"` in a Linux package and as `QT_INSTALL_PREFIX` + `"/include"` in Windows builds (both MSVC and MinGW).

As an alternative to `patch_qmake_qt_key.py` script, which indeed works if supplied with proper key names, I created [QmakePatch](https://github.com/SamsonovAnton/QmakePatch) utility, which you may find helpful either per se or for its documentation: `README.md` lists key names and other technical details for known Qt / QMake versions (GitHub displays that on the repo's home page).

---

However, regarding *relative* paths, I strongly doubt that it is a good idea to use them in `Makefile`s, since current working path is usually changed several times during the build process. Even if you try to `make INSTALL_ROOT=./destdir install`, for example, it will result in each sub-project being installed to their own `./destdir` subdirectory — not the one in the topmost directory you invoke Make from.